# d3 animate line graph horizontally by changing parameterized function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to animate a gaussian by changing its mean and variance with d3.  The problem I'm having is that the points of the curve just translate across the Y axis, so it looks like one gaussian going down and another going up.  How could I modify this code to achieve what I'm looking for?

```
//Define the curves, this would be replaced by a function call
var g1 = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0.0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 0.0}, ...];
var g2 = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0.0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 0.0}, ...];

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d) { return d.x*2; })
                     .y(function(d) { return d.y * 2000; })
                     .interpolate("linear");

var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
                     .attr("d", lineFunction(g1))
                     .attr("stroke", "blue")
                     .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                     .attr("fill", "none");

lineGraph.transition().duration(1000).attr('d', lineFunction(g2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x22xE/104/

Comment: Instead of interpolating the points (which is what d3's path transition does) you need to animate the mean and variance values from which the points are derived. You can do it with a custom tween that generates and draws a new curve at each frame of the animation, based on the interpolated mean and variance. It's a similar idea to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2983699) which tweens an axis's domain rather than its ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to meetamit for the help, here's the (messy) solution:

```
var svg = d3.select('#myelement').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 200);

function gaussian(u, s, x) {
    var m = s * Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);
    var e = Math.exp(-Math.pow(x - u, 2) / (2 * s * s));
    return (e * 1000 / m).toFixed(3); // toFixed is important
}

function pdf(u, s, resolution) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i += resolution) {
        result.push({x: i, y: gaussian(u, s, i)})
    }
    return result;
}

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                         .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                         .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(pdf(0,5,1)))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");
lineGraph.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween('d', function() {
    return function(t) {
        return lineFunction(pdf(150 * t, 5, 1));
    }
  })
```